# Django development stage best practice

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

I am going to be working on a Django Project for my final requirement in school, and I am wondering if I should use `PostgreSQL` on development stage or if I should stick with built-in `sqlite3` during development. I am worried if I used sqlite3 on development stage there will be problems with migrations if I switch to PostgreSQL on Production.

And is PostgeSQL is the best database for Django?

Comment: Check out https://digiqt.com/blog/django-best-practices-for-scalable-apps.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use PostgreSQL in deployment, which is a good choice, I suggest you to use the same on development. You might want to use things that are exclusive to PostgreSQL,like [PostgreSQL exclusive fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/) or [PostgreSQL functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/functions/) or [lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/), and you can't do that if you don't have PostgreSQL in your development environment as well.

Comment: thanks for that, seems a little bit complex. But let's say, I decided not to use PostgreSQL on development stage, will my I be facing some problems migrating from sqlite3 to PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes there will be problems and those problems might be considerable. SQLite3 and Postgres **are not the same**. It would be awful to not complete the project because of them.  IMHO never develop for one database and expect the result to run on another - *it just does not happen*.  Download Postgres and install it locally for your development (even if it is older the same version as the final implementation). You may even learn something extra along the way. And if you have issues the SO community here to help.